# Optimization and Local minimizer

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, inner-products

Suppose that f is a G-differential function on $R^{N}_{+}$ that has a local minimum at a point h. Prove that h is a solution of the system
$\nabla f(x)\ge 0$ and $\bigl\langle x,\nabla f(x)\bigr\rangle=0$

Anyone know how to prove this? Thank you.